# How would you describe this shape?

Tags: shapes

I am trying to describe [this weapon](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3f/75/f6/3f75f6b82f62acae117d92ab84bec1e7.jpg) from a video game ([Daggertail from Prince of Persia : Two Thrones](https://princeofpersia.fandom.com/wiki/Daggertail)). However, I am not sure how to describe the shape of the links which make up the daggertail (not the end). The closest fitting description that I could find is "*Serrated metal links*" which does not seem adequate. Would anyone of you be able to help give a more proper description of the individual link ?

Comment: Try typing "wing shaped" into Google Images. Meanwhile, voting to close.

Comment: They look a bit “bat-shaped” to me.

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as opinion-based. One suggestion would be "like razor wire".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole Daggertail is evocative of a dragons tail complete with [serpentine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serpentine) barbs.

Thus you can conjure with those words,

> The links produce a metallic serpentine barbed chain.

OR you could describe them as toothed

> Deadly due to the double sided dragons teeth barbs each metallic link is a
>   weapon in its own right.